# How to make PHP video redictor

Tags: php, security, video, jwplayer

I apologize for my English in advance. I would like to ask how to do a

> "secret url" --> someurl/video/5s5sd77sd/2sd2sd8d/dsdsd.mp4 --> someone.com/hash someurl.mp4 exmaple  --> someoneurl/dsdsdssa.mp4

The player will be someoneurl but to take the data from someurl

```
$url = "someurl/video/5s5sd77sd/2sd2sd8d/dsdsd.mp4";
$generate = md5($url);
$newurl = "someoneurl/$generate.mp4"; //--> this url will be for jwplayer
```

How to make a link in the player $newurl retrieved data from $url ? Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$newurl = "someoneurl/$generate.mp4"; --> this url will be for jwplayer
```

Should be:

```
$newurl = "someoneurl/".$generate.".mp4"; --> this url will be for jwplayer
```

The way you are doing it literally creates a URL with `$generate` in it. If you use the dots you can concatenate the strings with your variable.

Comment: I understand this, but how do I get those data at a new url address?
How to make a link in the player $newurl retrieved data from $url ?

Comment: @user3502252 Could you please provide me with some more code to see how you use the player you are referring to?

Comment: Here is testing player https://do98ad.tk/video/f1ebddb3aad21aa5abdc 
(show source code)

Comment: @user3502252 In your jwplayer script on you have this line:
file: "linktothevideoyouwouldliketoplay",

Use the following to insert your url: 
file : <?php echo $newurl ; ?>' ,

Comment: I know, but i need from $url (original) make $newurl (new) 
which will take the data from the original url...

Comment: When you get to the page you insert that data by using: `$newurl = "someoneurl/".$generate.".mp4"; --> this url will be for jwplayer` so you can then pass the `$newurl` into the script.

Comment: I know... $newurl how to recive data..?

Comment: We might have a miscommunication here. Either I don't understand what you are trying or you don't understand my answer. Maybe this should make my answer a bit more clear:

Somewhere in your PHP file you have the following:
`$url = "someurl/video/5s5sd77sd/2sd2sd8d/dsdsd.mp4";
$generate = md5($url);
$newurl = "someoneurl/$generate.mp4"; //--> this url will be for jwplayer`

So your `$newurl` variable is filled with the link to the video?

This means the data is available for you to use `file : <?php echo $newurl ; ?>` in your script to insert it into the player.

Comment: Do you have skype?

Comment: This is the new address that will be used in the player <?php echo $newurl ; ?> 
how does this url get video data from the original address ..? This is what I need some data to get

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have Skype. But since you are putting the video link in the `$url` variable, you can use that to create the `$newurl`. Would you like to be able to change the `$url` value somewhere? If you link a user to the player, you can use something like a `$session` variable or cookies to do this.